# SystemStackError when array destructuring with splat operator

Tags: ruby

I have an application that gathers an (large-ish) amount of data into an array and appends it into an existing array.  When I use the splat operator (to use with `Array.push`), I get a `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` message.  'Large' is in the range of 150k entries (each entry contains additional objects).

What is the preferred method to merge large arrays in Ruby?

```
gathered_info = function_that_returns_a_large_array_of_hashes()
dump.push(*gathered_info)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a bunch of things to an array then the *splat* will need to expand those as individual arguments, each of which takes stack space. That's bad for large lists for reasons you've discovered.

You can always just use [`concat`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Array.html#method-i-concat) on the array directly:

```
dump.concat(gathered_info)
```

That's far less cumbersome.

You normally use a splat because there's no alternative that takes an array instead, but that's not the case here. `concat` does exactly what you need.